# Replacing labels when overlapping with another line layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, overlapping-features

I have a line feature layer with the name of streets. I want to render labels parallel on the line (the line has transparent color). I have another line feature layer often going parallel to the street layer.

I need to move labels with a street name offset when they collide with this another layer. How can be it done?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the "prevent overlapping labels" box?

Comment: Where can I find this box? Placement, rendering bookmark? I didnt find it..

Comment: Placement, at the very bottom.

Comment: You mean obstacle setting? Yes, I checked it.